# Getting exception in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to empty table by below code using javascript :

```
var customerDetailsTable = document.getElementById("tableID");
customerDetailsTable.innerHTML = "";
```

But getting `unknown runtime` exception in IE8.

How to solve this issue?

Solution :
    Instead of this : `customerDetailsTable.innerHTML = "";`

```
Use this:

while (customerDetailsTable.hasChildNodes()) {   
    customerDetailsTable.removeChild(customerDetailsTable.firstChild);
}
```

Comment: What kind of Exception? What is the error message? Can you provide your html code as well?

Comment: Please provide some more details.

Comment: http://www.theogray.com/blog/2009/06/internet-explorer-unknown-runtime-error